# How to install raspberry pi kernel headers of which version matches with $(uname -r) version

Tags: raspberry-pi, linux-kernel, linux-kernel-headers

## Title

I want to install raspberry pi kernel headers of which version matches with `$(uname -r)` version because I'll develop kernel modules on Raspberry Pi.

## Description

I tried to execute `sudo apt install raspberrypi-kernel-headers`, but the header version doesn't match with the one of `$(uname -r)`. In addition to do this, I tried to do **bellow trials** but the header version doesn't match with the one of `$(uname -r)`.

Is there are ways how to install raspberry pi kernel headers of which version matches with `$(uname -r)` version  ?

## What I try to do :

#### 1. Simply Tring to execute `sudo apt install raspberrypi-kernel-headers`

Reference : https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/linux_kernel.html#kernel-headers

```
uname -r  # Check the current ver
> 5.15.76-v7+

ls /usr/src/
> sense-hat

sudo apt install raspberrypi-kernel-headers

ls -1 /usr/src/
> linux-headers-5.15.84+
> linux-headers-5.15.84-v7+
> linux-headers-5.15.84-v7l+   
> sense-hat
```

There is installed `linux-headers-5.15.84-v7+` but is doesn't match with the `$(uname -r)` version.

#### 2. Do `rpi-update` to update the kernel to the lastest, then execute `sudo apt install raspberrypi-kernel-headers`

```
sudo rpi-update
sudo reboot
uname -r
> 5.15.89-v7+  # update to the lastest ver !
sudo apt update
sudo apt dist-upgrade -y
sudo apt autoremove -y
sudo apt autoclean
sudo reboot

sudo apt install raspberrypi-kernel-headers 
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree... Done
> Reading state information... Done
> raspberrypi-kernel-headers is already the newest version (1:1.20230106-1).
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
ls -1 /usr/src/
> linux-headers-5.15.84+
> linux-headers-5.15.84-v7+
> linux-headers-5.15.84-v7l+   
> sense-hat
```

The kernel is updated to `5.15.89-v7+` but kernel header does not update, still `5.15.84-v7+`.

#### 3. --reinstall raspberrypi-kernel then install raspberrypi-kernel-headers

Reference : https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/63879/installed-kernel-headers-and-uname-r-differ

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel
sudo reboot
uname -r
> 5.15.89-v7+
sudo apt-get install raspberrypi-kernel-headers
ls -1 /usr/src/
> linux-headers-5.15.84+
> linux-headers-5.15.84-v7+
> linux-headers-5.15.84-v7l+   
> sense-hat
```

The kernel is not updated, and kernel headers is too.

## Appendix

#### 1. /lib/modules

After above procedure, there are the kernel modules of which version is the same as `$(uname -r)` version.

```
ls /lib/modules
5.15.84+  5.15.84-v7+  5.15.84-v7l+  5.15.84-v8+  5.15.89+  5.15.89-v7+  5.15.89-v7l+  5.15.89-v8+
```

#### 2. apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)

As like ubuntu or debian, I tried to `apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`, but It was an invalid command.

```
apt search linux-headers-$(uname -r)
> Sorting... Done
> Full Text Search... Done

sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree... Done
> Reading state information... Done
> E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-5.15.84-v7
> E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'linux-headers-5.15.84-v7'
> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-5.15.84-v7'
```

Comment: I think that the kernel headers version must match with the $(uname -r) version when developing kernel modules. So I hope I can match header ver to $(uname -r) ver , or vise versa.

Comment: The raspi ver : `Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Plus Rev 1.3`, 
Linux ver is : `Linux raspberrypi 5.15.84-v7+ #1613 SMP Thu Jan 5 11:59:48 GMT 2023 armv7l GNU/Linux`

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use `rpi-update` now that the kernel is packaged in the standard repository.  To install the proper kernel and headers, do the following:

```
apt install raspberrypi-kernel raspberrypi-kernel-headers
```

`rpi-update` should not really be needed by most users and I haven't used it for years.  A fairly up-to-date kernel is already available via the raspberrypi-kernel package.