# kernel headers missing build directory

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi

raspberry pi. i have kernel version 4.19.97-v7l+ installed. I am trying to install the driver for the RTL8812BU wifi adapter. I am installing the repository https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu-20210702. When I run `./install-driver.sh` it gives the error:

`Your kernel header files aren't properly installed. Please consult your distro documentation or user support forums.`

I tried to install `raspberrypi-kernel-headers`, but it gives the same error. the problem is that `/lib/modules/4.19.97-v7l+` does not contain the build directory that is needed to install the driver.

```
xrou@raspberrypi:~ $ uname -r
4.19.97-v7l+
```

```
xrou@raspberrypi:~ $ ls /lib/modules/`uname -r`
kernel         modules.alias.bin  modules.builtin.bin  modules.dep.bin  modules.order    modules.symbols
modules.alias  modules.builtin    modules.dep          modules.devname  modules.softdep  modules.symbols.bin
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** Just to provide a more wholistic answer, the dev was already aware of this issue, and provides a potential fix in his [FAQ section](https://github.com/morrownr/88x2bu-20210702/blob/main/FAQ.md). He concurs with it being a 64 bit vs 32 bit OS issue.

I encountered the exact same problem on my Raspberry Pi 4 B (arm64), running the latest kernel.

```
user@pi:~ $ uname -r
6.1.0-rpi4-rpi-v8
```

For me, installing a new 64-bit Version of Raspberry Pi OS instead of the 32-bit version solved the issue for me, though that might not be a viable option for you. Maybe deleting the directory in question and re-installing kernel headers might help? *(link 3)*

In my case, i suspect it to be some compatibility issue between a 64-bit kernel and 32-bit OS *(link 1)*, again whether that is applicable to your situation i do not know.

I would maybe check if (and which) of the listed modules under `ls /lib/modules` contain a build directory, since the contents of my `/lib/modules` directory changed quite a bit after the reinstall.

```
user@pi:~ $ ls /lib/modules
6.1.0-13-arm64  6.1.0-rpi4-rpi-2712  6.1.0-rpi4-rpi-v8  6.1.21-v8+
```

unfortunately i can't show you the output before the reinstall, however the two leftmost directories were definitely not present prior, though that might just be `dkms` related.

Also some further resources that might be of help, as they helped me. Good luck!

1. [32 bit OS, 64 bit kernel issue](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=349070)
2. [Different (older) driver repository](https://github.com/fastoe/RTL8812BU_for_Raspbian)
3. [(Re)installing kernel & kernel-headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75216940/how-to-install-raspberry-pi-kernel-headers-of-which-version-matches-with-uname)